# How to pass a critical data from JavaScript to flask securely?

Tags: javascript, flask, paypal

I want to transfer some details provided in JSON object when paypal payment is completed to flask route. Currectly what I have done is that I have hidden form field and when the payment is approved I pass the values to the form and then submit the form so that the data from form can be accessed in the flask using form.fieldname.data and get the amount paid. But there are too much risks in this, the client could easily change the amount field in form to any amount just by inspect element.

my flask function

```
@app.route('/addpoints', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_points():
    form = PointsForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.amount.data)
```

This is the Paypal function on payment being approved.

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        console.log('hello');
        document.getElementById("name").value = details.payer.name.given_name;
        document.getElementById("paidamount").value = details.purchase_units[0].amount.value;
        button.click(); // submit button
});
}
```

How can I transfer this data securely so that the client can't edit the form before submission? I thought about saving the json object to the server folder then from flask accessing the file, but still the client can just edit the json object being saving by giving a json object in the saving file section.

Comment: When the amount is approved? Why don't you send the amount to flask when the user pays it. How iser is paying the amount, through input form? Another thing is rather using forms you can use [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) or [fetch api](https://towardsdatascience.com/talking-to-python-from-javascript-flask-and-the-fetch-api-e0ef3573c451) ,which will send the amount through javascript. If you want , I can provide you an example of ajax using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store information in a server, you should not be using a client-side actions.order.create / actions.order.capture .  Change to a proper server-side integration.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

As for transferring data to your server, do not use a form POST after capture.  Include the information in the call that makes the capture, as an additional body in the fetch call.